# Install Ubuntu on Separate HDD - Win 7 Error

Tags: boot, hard-drive, ssd

So, I decided that installing Ubuntu and re-learning Linux would be beneficial. I downloaded Ubuntu (Latest version), unplugged all other HDD/SSD that I have in my PC and the install went perfect and the OS runs perfect. However, I plugged my slave drive and my SSD(Win7 64bit HP) back in and win7 gives me an error ([Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHKpS.jpg). The only way to fix it is by either unplugging the HDD with Ubuntu or inserting the win7 disk every time you boot. What is going on?

Comment: You may get a little more response on super user as this is a little bit more on the windows side. But my advice is this: enable hot plugging of the slot your Ubuntu drive is in, reboot (with Ubuntu unplugged), plug it back in after it boots and see if that works (Warning! Possibly unsafe!)